# How to do a DAP verification in .cap files loading?

Tags: javacard, globalplatform, jcop

I want to install a *.cap* file. But I want the Card Manager to do a **DAP** verification during uploading my file. What shall I do? Does it check the DAP by default or I must use some parameters in the installation process?

My smart card is a *Java Card 3.0.1* that is compliant with *Global Platform 2.2.1*

Note that I am using *Eclipse* and *JCDK* for developing applets and I use *gp* and *JCManager* for uploading applets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to your questions :

- I want the Card Manager to do a `DAP` verification during uploading my file. What shall I do?

There are following two scenarios, if any one of the scenario will occur then `DAP block` will necessary in the Load block :

1.If any Security Domain has the `Mandated DAP Verification privilege` and if so: Authentication data (DAP Block identifying the above Security Domain) should be present in the Load File.

2.If the associated Security Domain has the `DAP Verification privilege` and if so: Authentication data (DAP Block identifying the associated Security Domain) should be present in the Load File.

- Does it check the `DAP` by default or I must use some parameters in the installation process?

You need to set appropriate privilege during Installation process of security domain (as explained above). `DAP verification keys` are also need to be put in security domain which will verify the DAP. `DAP Keys` can be of RSA or DES and must be put with a specific key version.

For more details please refer **Global Platform specification GPC_Specification_2.2.1**

Comment: Thank you. And how I can create `.CAP` files that containing authentication data? As far as I know, when I use converter to convert my `.class` files to `.cap`, nothing except than the program include in the output. How I add this verification data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sim alliance loader tool for installing applet with mandatory DAP verification you can find tool [here](http://www.simalliance.org/en?t=/documentManager/sfdoc.file.supply&s=Vxts8L4bkckNt2Pk0cJ&fileID=1335792495743).

Comment: As far as I know using DAP verification is optional, right? i.e : Maybe the card support it and maybe not, but if support it, user can select to use it or not, is it right?

Comment: if DAP verification is mandatory in configuration then it is mandate to verify DAP.

Comment: You can read global plateform specs [here](http://www.globalplatform.org/specificationscard.asp) go to page 74.